# Why is Meteor Template Object Not Defined?

Tags: javascript, meteor, spacebars

I've been following a tutorial to make a simple forum, after finally getting all the code get together, it tells me 'Template is not defined'

Code of forum.html

```
<head>
  <title>Forum</title>
</head>
<body>
  {{> form}}
  {{> posts}}
</body>

<template name="posts">
  <h1>Posts</h1>
  <ul>
    {{#each posts}}
      <li>
        <h3>{{title}}</h3>
        <p>{{body}}</p>
      </li>
    {{/each}}
  </ul>
</template>


<template name="form">
  <form>
    <label>Post Title:
      <input type="text" id="title" />
    </label>
    <label>Post Body:
      <textarea id="body"></textarea>
    </label>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="submit"/>
  </form>
</template>
```

Code of forum.js:

```
var Posts = new Meteor.Collection('posts');
  if (Meteor.isClient) {
    Template.posts.helpers({
      Posts: function() {
        return Posts.find();
      }
    });
  }

Template.form.events = {
  'click #submit': function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var title = $('#title').val();
    var body = $('#body').val();
    Posts.insert({
      title: title,
      body: body
    });
    $('#title, #body').val('');
  }
};
```

Here's some of the output I get from meteor

```
W20150211-02:01:42.086(0)? (STDERR)           
W20150211-02:01:42.088(0)? (STDERR) /home/ubuntu/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.40.1ef5dzv++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_64/dev_bundle/server-lib/node_modules/fibers/future.js:173
W20150211-02:01:42.088(0)? (STDERR)                                             throw(ex);
W20150211-02:01:42.088(0)? (STDERR)                                                   ^
W20150211-02:01:42.091(0)? (STDERR) ReferenceError: Template is not defined
W20150211-02:01:42.091(0)? (STDERR)     at app/forum.js:10:1
W20150211-02:01:42.091(0)? (STDERR)     at app/forum.js:23:3
W20150211-02:01:42.091(0)? (STDERR)     at /home/ubuntu/workspace/forum/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:205:10
W20150211-02:01:42.092(0)? (STDERR)     at Array.forEach (native)
W20150211-02:01:42.092(0)? (STDERR)     at Function._.each._.forEach (/home/ubuntu/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.40.1ef5dzv++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_64/dev_bundle/server-lib/node_modules/underscore/underscore.js:79:11)
W20150211-02:01:42.092(0)? (STDERR)     at /home/ubuntu/workspace/forum/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:116:5
=> Exited with code: 8
=> Your application is crashing. Waiting for file change.
```

Comment: fyi - i had this same error because i accidentally moved one of my clent template folders outside the client folder into the root.  so my moving from /partners/partner.html back to /client/partners/partner.html all is better.

Answer (score 7):

There's 2 problems with your code :

- Template definition is not available on server so you need to wrap the `Template.form` definition in a `Meteor.isClient` condition, or better yet, separate your code using `client` and `server` directories.
- Correct event maps definition needs to use this syntax : `Template.form.events({...});` not `Template.form.events={...};`

Answer (score 1):

The reason why you are seeing the error that you are is because your second reference to the `Template` object is not specified to be running explicitly on the client, like your first reference to `Template` is. The `Template` object is only available on the client, as detailed in [this section](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/templates_api) of the Meteor documentation. You would just simply need to bring the closing bracket of your `if(Meteor.isClient){}` code block down to be below your `Template.form.events` definition.

This, however, brings up the subject of application structure and how to avoid issues like this in the future during further development of your application. If you take a look at [this documentation](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/structuringyourapp), it is highly recommended that you divide your JS code up into at least two different locations to avoid encountering issues like this in the future. I would suggest moving your `var Posts = new Meteor.Collection('posts');` line into a JS file within a top-level `server` folder (`name_of_app_directory/server`), and moving all of the other JS code into a JS file within a top-level `client` folder (`name_of_app_directory/client`). This way, you can eliminate the need to also include the `if(Meteor.isClient){}` block in your code, and no more chance for seeing the error that you have.

Also, final thing to consider. When defining your template `events` object, define it similarly to how you have already defined your template `helpers` object (`Template.form.events({...})`). For more information on this, see [this documentation](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/template_events).